# transition effect not working on correct element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am in the middle of making an accordion like hidden menu and I wanted to make the submenu have a specific feature. I saw FelixWastal's Codepen http://codepen.io/felixw/pen/Hqmbu and I thought that would be something creative to add for the hidden submenu. But after I coded it, the feature seen in the example for some reason affects the main `ul`.

Here's my current try at this issue: http://codepen.io/PorototypeX/pen/swvtc

Comment: What is the "specific feature" you wanted to add?

Comment: @TimSPQR I wanted it so that when you hover over it, it looks like the border to the left expanded out so that the background is one solid color

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? You have two lis (HOME, HOME2) HOME with brown slider, HOME2 with blue slider. Do you want to have one 'double-slider' that comes out and covers both HOME and HOME2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll guess that you're trying to make a submenu, and style it differently.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/kwSrV/)

HTML

```
<nav>
  <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Shop</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Submenu</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
  <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS

```
nav a:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; 
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
  z-index: -1;
}
nav a:hover:nth-child(3):before { width: 100%;}
nav a:hover:nth-child(3) span { color: white;}
```

NB: if FelixWastal is out there...congratulations on a beautiful piece of work - visually and programmatically.